# Bind 2 Observable collections to eachother

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, observablecollection, dependency-properties

I've got a `UserControl` which has an `ObservableCollection` as a `DP` in his code behind file. This control is used  as part of a `TabControl` (`TabItem`).

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OrderListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("OrderList", typeof(ObservableCollection<Order>), typeof(OrderHistoryControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Order>()));

public ObservableCollection<Order> OrderList
{
  get { return (ObservableCollection<Order>)GetValue(OrderListProperty); }
  set { SetValue(OrderListProperty, value); }
}
```

Now in my `TabControl ViewModel` I have the same type of `DP`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OrdersProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Orders", typeof(ObservableCollection<Order>), typeof(AccountViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Order>()));

public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
{
  get { return (ObservableCollection<Order>)GetValue(OrdersProperty); }
  set { SetValue(OrdersProperty, value); }
}
```

In the `XAML` of the `TabControl` the `OrderList` property of the `UserControl` is bound to the `Orders` property of the `TabControl Viewmodel`.

```
<Grid>
    <my:OrderHistoryControl x:Name="orderHistoryControl"
                              OrderList="{Binding Orders, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              ExpanderOrderDetailsHeader="TEST TEST" />
</Grid>
```

However, when I fill the `ObservableCollection Orders` (in `TabControl ViewModel`) the `ObservableCollection OrderList` on my `UserControl` is not updated. The `PropertyChangedCallback` isn't even fired.

I have some other controls on my usercontrol and when I change their text fields via the `TabControl ViewModel` that works fine. So I know there is something wrong with the binding between the 2 `ObservableCollection`s. Any idea?

Comment: If you say "when I fill the ObservableCollection Orders (in tabcontrol viewmodel) the ObservableCollection OrderList on my usercontrol is not updated" are you expecting the OrderList property to be changed? Or are no items added to the list? Also don't create an element with new inside the Register method of your dependency property. Otherwise each instant of that class, share the same defaul value, in this case one collection.

Comment: @dowhilefor Indeed. When I fill Orders it should update the OrderList in my usercontrol. I removed the new for both dependency properties but still Orderlist is not updated.

Comment: Its important to get the distinction here: When you say "it should update the OrderList" then i reply: No it shouldn't, because you are changing something _in_ the property, not the property itself. If you assign a new collection which actually call the setter of the collection, then it will also update the property on your view. Also i strongly advise you not to use DependencyProperties in your view model.

Comment: How is your `ObservableCollection` created, and how is the `PropertyChanged` notification set up? Also I agree with @dowhilefor that you really shouldn't be using DPs in your ViewModel. Think of DPs like this: they're a pointer to another property, not an actual property itself. So you're telling your `OrderList` to go look in the `Orders` DP to get it's value, and you're probably telling `Orders` to go look somewhere in memory to get it's value. My best guess is your PropertyChange notification is not getting fired because "somewhere in memory" does not raise a property change notification :)